# Drupal: Translating the Contact-Form

Tags: drupal, localization, drupal-7

I want to use the default Drupal contact form for my website, but the labels("Your Name","Category") are in english an I need them in german.
Maybe I'm blind but i couldn't find a way to edit these labels.

So I googled it and found this Module: https://www.drupal.org/node/1396984

I installed the module and followed the guide, but it seems that I can only localize the categories or the auto-reply, because I still see english lables.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there just no easy way to change those lables?

thanks

I'm using the latest Version of Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the i18n module - https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n (if you haven't already). Then you can translate those strings ("Your name","Category") from the translate interface located at http://yoursite.com/admin/config/regional/translate/translate *

**Note**: If the strings don't appear in the translate interface try displaying the page containing them (the contact page) *in a language other than the default one*. This will register them for translation.

** replace yoursite.com with the address of the site you are developing*

P.S. If you are going to make a multilingual site, I suggest you enable all relevant i18n submodules and import the drupal core translation for the languages you need from https://localize.drupal.org/translate/downloads

Comment: I got it working, thanks, I just misunderstood how this module works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is the Localization client.

https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_client

Comment: I have already installed this module, it contains the "Contact translation"-Module